# int type > operator error in Groovy

Tags: groovy, operators

Using Groovy, the > operator warns that the type matches wrong.

This is a problem:

```
def greaterThan50(nums){
   def result = []
   nums.each{ num ->
      if(num > 50)
         result << num
   result
}
def test = greaterThan50([2, 3, 50, 62, 11, 2999])
assert test.contains(62)
```

The line " if(num > 50)" create the warning.

[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#compareTo(java.lang.Integer). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.

50 is int type (and also an object as I know) but the site's example is like this. (site is here : http://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/getting-started/groovy-basics.html#groovy-basics)

```
def greaterThan50(nums){
   def result = []
   for (num in nums){
       if(num > 50){
            result << num
       }
   }
   result
}
def test = greaterThan50([2, 5, 62, 50, 25, 88])
```

How do I change code for comparing two int types?

Comment: Also, use `findAll` instead of `each` and `<<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For type-checking to work properly, you need to specify argument and return types explicitly. You also missed a closing brace to end the closure after `each`.

```
List<Integer> greaterThan50(List<Integer> nums) {
    def result = []
    nums.each { num ->
        if (num > 50)
            result << num
    }
    result
}

def test = greaterThan50([2, 3, 50, 62, 11, 2999])
assert test.contains(62)
```

A groovyier way to archive the same functionality would be

```
nums.findAll { it > 50 }
```

which creates a new list and adds all numbers that satisfy the condition for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to suppress the warning, effectively making that code statically checked, you can declare the data type of the incoming parameter explicitly.

```
def greaterThan50(List<Integer> nums){
```

This will allow static type checking to link the iteration element type to Integer.